# Checking if an attribute with no value exists with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve label text next to checkboxes on a form from only those that are checked.

Here is the html:

```
<div class="x-panel-bwrap" id="ext-gen1956"><div 
class="x-panel-body" id="ext-gen1957" style="width: 226px;">
<div class="x-form-check-wrap" id="ext-gen1959"><input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1609" name="ext-comp-1609" class=" x-form-checkbox x-form-field">
<label for="ext-comp-1609" class="x-form-cb-label" id="ext-gen1960">labeltext1</label></div>
<div class="x-form-check-wrap" id="ext-gen1961"><input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1607" name="ext-comp-1607" class=" x-form-checkbox x-form-field">
<label for="ext-comp-1607" class="x-form-cb-label" id="ext-gen1962">labeltext2</label></div>
<div class="x-form-check-wrap" id="ext-gen1963"><input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" id="ext-comp-1605" name="ext-comp-1605" class=" x-form-checkbox x-form-field" checked="">
<label for="ext-comp-1605" class="x-form-cb-label" id="ext-gen1964">labeltext3</label></div>
```

The label I want to get that is beside a checked box is differentiated by the attribute checked=""

```
for checkboxes in soup.find_all('input', attrs={"id":"ext-comp-1609"}):
    if checkboxes.find('input', attrs={"checked":""}):
        label_1 = soup.find('label',{'id':'ext-gen1960'}).text
        print(label_1)
    else:
        continue

for checkboxes in soup.find_all('input', attrs={"id":"ext-comp-1607"}):
    if checkboxes.find('input', attrs={"checked":""}):
        label_2 = soup.find('label',{'id':'ext-gen1962'}).text
        print(label_2)
    except:
        continue

for checkboxes in soup.find_all('input', attrs={"id":"ext-comp-1605"}):
    if checkboxes.find('input', attrs={"checked":""}):
        label_3 = soup.find('label',{'id':'ext-gen1964'}).text
        print(label_3)
    else:
        continue
```

My problem is that this grabs the labels whether they are checked or not. I have tried using has_attr() as well but it yields the same results.

Tried solutions:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
for checkbox in soup.find_all('input', checked=True):
    print(checkbox.label.get_text())
```

and

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser')
for checkbox in soup.select('input[checked]'):
    print(checkbox.label.get_text())

for checkbox in soup.find_all('input', checked=True):
    print(checkbox.find_next_sibling("label").get_text())
```

Answer (score 3):

You should apply the `checked=True` check for all the `input` elements. Then, get the inner `label` element and it's text:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")
for checkbox in soup.find_all('input', checked=True):
    print(checkbox.label.get_text())
```

Note that for `html5lib` or `lxml`, you would need a different way to get to the labels:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html5lib")
for checkbox in soup.find_all('input', checked=True):
    print(checkbox.find_next_sibling("label").get_text())
```

---

Works for me on your input data:

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: data = """your HTML here"""

In [3]: soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "html.parser")

In [4]: for checkbox in soup.find_all('input', checked=True):
   ...:     print(checkbox.label.get_text())
   ...:     
Can Submit Expense Reports
```

Comment: +1 - Or an attribute selector: `soup.select('input[checked]')`, the value of the `checked` attribute really doesn't matter since the checkbox will always be checked if the attribute is present (i.e., `checked="false"` is [still checked](https://jsfiddle.net/5b5ek7uc/)).

Comment: I am receiving: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text', does this mean it is not finding anything?

Comment: @nvachhan please see the note about the other way to get to the `label` elements - looks like this is it.

Comment: @alecxe I've edited my question with the solutions I have tried and am still receiving the same error

Comment: @nvachhan okay, have you tried the `find_next_sibling()` variant?

Comment: @alecxe I tried it, its free of error but is not able to grab the data for some reason

Comment: @nvachhan okay, can I ask you about two things? Which parser are you using (`html.parser`, `html5lib` or `lxml`)? And, could you dump the form to HTML and post it's HTML to the question? (I suspect the actual HTML you are dealing with might be different from what you've already posted)

Comment: @alecxe I've included the html code for the whole form now, I am using 'html.parser'

Comment: @nvachhan interesting, just executed the code against your HTML, works for me (see the updated answer). Thanks!

Comment: That is strange. I am using selenium to get to the form hence soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, 'html.parser') but I don't understand why it would not work, it definitely recognizes the page since it is able to pull other data off of it.

Comment: @nvachhan when you get the page source - are you sure the page is completely loaded and the HTML of the form is exactly as you are expecting it to be? (thinking - timing problem?)

Comment: I have encountered that before so I added time.sleep(5) but it did not help

Comment: @nvachhan okay, assuming 5 seconds was enough and it is not a timing problem, could it be that the form is inside an iframe?

Comment: @alecxe I gave it 15sec and still the same. The form does seem to be inside an iframe

Comment: @nvachhan yeah, this is the problem then. You need to switch into the context of the `iframe` and then get the page source.

Comment: @alecxe but if this is the case then how am I able to pull all the label text with my old code?

Comment: @nvachhan I'm not sure, I have only episodes to work with, don't have a complete problem in front of me. Though, it sounds like you have everything to finish it :)

Answer (score -1):

BeautifulSoup check `checked` attribute with `True` or `False`, not `""`.

so you can change like this:

```
for checkboxes in soup.find_all('input', attrs={"id":"ext-comp-1609"}):
    if checkboxes.find('input', attrs={"checked":True}):
        label_1 = soup.find('label',{'id':'ext-gen1960'}).text
        print(label_1)
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Hmm, this makes sense but this time it yields no results.